# Is there no way to find the real constructor of an object in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm reviewing ECMAScript 5.1 Specification kinda seriously.

And I'm curious if there is a way to tell what the "real constructor function" of an object in ES5. ( not the explicit "constructor" property )

According to the spec, explicit "constructor" property is just a **initial** back-reference from the *byproduct* object of a function object to the function object.

(Here, the *byproduct* is the object which is initially pointed by the function object's explicit "prototype" property.)

So, explicit "constructor" property has nothing to do with the real constructor of an object:

```
function Foo(name){ this.name = name; }
var foo = new Foo("Brian");
var bar = { a: 10, b: function(){ if(this.name) return this.name; }};
Foo.prototype = bar;
var foo2 = new Foo("John");   // Let me call Foo as "real constructor" of foo2
```

Here, even though foo2 was created by Foo, since Foo.prototype was pointing to bar at the moment of creation of foo2, so foo2's internal [[Prototype]] gets to point to bar, and we can check this by:

```
Object.getPrototypeOf(foo2) === bar   // true
```

Since foo2 doesn't have own "constructor" property as usual, so, reading foo2.constructor is actually [[Prototype]] chain lookup, that is, foo2.constructor --> (( foo2.[[Prototype]] )).constructor --> bar.constructor which is Object, not Foo.

You can check this by:

```
foo2.constructor === Foo         // false
foo2.constructor === Object      // true
```

Finally, is there no way to find Foo from the object foo2?

ADD:
I'm talking about ES5. Please do not bring anything engine-dependent or ES6-thingy (e.g. `__proto__` )

Comment: Well I'm going to go out on a limb here and say that it is not possible. As far as I know, there is nothing that solidly links the constructor function with the constructed object. You can change `Foo.prototype` after you created the object and even `foo2 instanceof Foo` will not work anymore. Just think of the constructor function as a blue print. You use it to create an object but after you created it, there is nothing that prevents you of doing totally different things to both of them.

Comment: also, don't forget that it's perfectly possible for a constructor to return an entirely new object instead of the implicit `return this`, in which case there is absolutely _no link_ back to the function that created it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, the language does not natively offer any feature that does this.

If we consult the [spec on the `new` operator](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.2.2), we see it is largely a call to a function's `[[Construct]]` internal method. Turning our attention to [`[[Construct]]`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-13.2.2), we see:

> When the [[Construct]] internal method for a Function object *F* is called with a possibly empty list of arguments, the following steps are taken:
>
> 1. Let *obj* be a newly created native ECMAScript object.
> 2. Set all the internal methods of *obj* as specified in 8.12.
> 3. Set the [[Class]] internal property of *obj* to "`Object`".
> 4. Set the [[Extensible]] internal property of obj to `true`.
> 5. Let *proto* be the value of calling the [[Get]] internal property of F with argument "`prototype`".
> 6. If Type(*proto*) is Object, set the [[Prototype]] internal property of *obj* to *proto*.
> 7. If Type(*proto*) is not Object, set the [[Prototype]] internal property of *obj* to the standard built-in Object prototype object as described in 15.2.4.
> 8. Let *result* be the result of calling the [[Call]] internal property of *F*, providing obj as the this value and providing the argument list passed into [[Construct]] as args.
> 9. If Type(*result*) is Object then return result.
> 10. Return *obj*.

As you can see in steps 5 through 7, the only handling of the object created by `new` does by the environment is to set its `[[Prototype]]` and then hand it off to the function's `[[Call]]` method for processing in step 8. If the value assigned to the object's `[[Prtototype]]` does not contain an accurate `constructor` property, there is no way to know what constructor function created an object.

You could, of course, store that information in your *own* constructor code by setting a value on the object at creation-time, but the JavaScript engine will not do it for you.

Comment: Okay, now it seems clear again. Actually, I was curious when the Chrome console spit out the **real constructor** correctly for the above example. So, it must be engine's internal implementation that is not exposed to public.